# Displaying EXR files in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, picturebox, freeimage

I'm struggling with FreeImage and the documentation is not helping me a lot!

I need to display a tif, an exr or an HDR image in a picturebox with C# and I'm not succeeding and I wonder how can I do it... I'm getting the error: Only bitmaps with type of FIT_BITMAP can be converted. ...

Can anyone help me with it ? I suppose I have to convert the tiff to a bitmap but I've tried but I don't know how I should do it yet ... Here is my code:

```
    FIBITMAP imageToDisplay = new FIBITMAP();
    imageToDisplay = FreeImage.Load(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_TIFF, i, FREE_IMAGE_LOAD_FLAGS.TIFF_CMYK);
    Bitmap bitmap = FreeImage.GetBitmap(imageToDisplay);
    pictureBox.Image = (Image)new Bitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to check the title after assigning the tags! :)

Answer (score 0):

For displaying TIFFs, `PictureBox.Image` takes a `System.Drawing.Image` object - and [`System.Drawing.Image.FromFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/stf701f5.aspx) supports TIFF images.

I can't see any need to involve any third party dependencies here. It's all built in to the framework.

```
pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(someImage);
```

If your TIFF isn't a file (e.g. if it's just a byte array or a MemoryStream) - that's okay too  - use [`Image.FromStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/93z9ee4x.aspx).

For unsupported file formats, your job is to convert them into a format supported by `System.Drawing.Image`. If this is not possible, you might not be able to use the `PictureBox` control for this job.

Perhaps the title of your question should be "Constructing Image objects from EXR files" or maybe "Displaying EXR files in Windows Forms" or similar.

Comment: Thank your for your help. Unfortunately the FromFile() gives me out of memory and the file is about 6mb .. the FromStream() gives me invalid parameter :( That is why I tried to go with FreeImage but I get Only bitmaps with type of FIT_BITMAP can be converted. :(

Comment: From the documentation for `Image.FromFile()`: "If the file does not have a valid image format or if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file, this method throws an OutOfMemoryException exception."

Comment: So it seems that my tiff is not supported .. Do you know how can I process it in order to be processed? Because it is a valid TIF file... Or else I have to convert it to bitmap with freeimage...

Comment: No. What drew you to FreeImage? Are you sure it can do what you are asking?

Comment: I've saw that is compatible with HDR, EXR and TIFF .. I can load the images but I'm not able to process them to show in the PictureBox :(